# Laravel Grouping users

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, phpmyadmin, login-control

I have encountered a problem, more of lack of knowleg. I would like to group my users in my database, so i have a row called groups with the int of 0-3. If the user has a value of zero then he/her isn't activated if the user is 1 the its the most basic form, if the user is 2 its a admin and 3 for super admin but i don't know how to check to see if the user is one or the other my code is below.
Much thanks to all.

```
public function postLogin(){
    $Validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'email' => 'required | email',
        'password' => 'required'
        ));
    if($Validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('account-Login-post')
        ->withErrors($Validator)
        ->withInput();
    }
    else{
        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
            'active' => 1,
            'groups' => 1 //I would like to check if the user has a value of 1-3 not just one.
            ));
        if($auth){
            return Redirect::intended('/');
        }

    }

    return Redirect::route('account-Login-post')
    ->with('global',"sorry");
}
```

Comment: i would acutally use `Auth::validate()` then a query builder to check the group is in an array using `whereBetween()`. Then I would use `Auth::login()` once I've identified that and done some logic against the result of the group.

Comment: I would rather suggest you use [Sentry2 by cartalyst](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry). It has groups integrated in its package. Though, the logic would be the same as described by @Ohgodwhy

Comment: If in the users table the field is called *groups*, It could be something like `Auth::user()->groups` , this will give you the the value of groups for the currently logged in user. Otherwise as the previous comment mentioned, try using the package.